# Neural ODEs: How many layers in a Neural ODE model?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, numerical-methods, neural-networks

I am trying to understand the original Chen et al., [Neural ODE paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.07366.pdf), but I am finding the language a bit confusing.

The main question is how many layers does one have in a Neural ODE? It seems the layers are residual network blocks. The analogy that the authors use is training a continuous-time or continuous-dept neural network.

The paper itself states:

> The main technical difficulty in training continuous-depth networks is
> performing reverse-mode differentiation (also known as
> backpropagation) through the ODE solver

But of course we cannot have a continuous-depth network, since a continuous-depth network has infinite layers. A computer cannot handle an object like that. So the key question is how many layers does a neural ode have? And as a follow on, how is that number of layers determined?

Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give a link to the paper?

Comment: @RobertLewis your wish is my command.

Comment: thanks it looks quite engaging I'll check it out

Comment: Is not the whole idea of neural ODE to interpret a recursive network as an ODE solved with a fixed-step method and then transferring that ODE to an adaptive-step method? The number of steps, recursions or layers would then be dynamically determined by the step-size controller of the method. This would be especially effective if the ODE converges to a stable state and the solver is A-stable, so that the step-size can increase without being bound by the stability region.